# Writing out a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, finance

Someone deposits money in a bank account at a continuous rate of $5000$ per year, and the account earns interest at a continuous rate of $7\%$ per year. Is the differential equation for the balance $B$ in dollars, as a function of years, t $$\frac{dB}{dt}=5000+0.07B?$$

Or do I not need the $5000$? Since the $5000$ are not deposited initially... Should the equation be $$\frac{dB}{dt}t=0.07B$$ instead?

Comment: Hmmm... I feel like it's something in-between the two. On the one hand you need to account for the balance and the interest, but that five grand is deposited continuously throughout the year, so I feel like it might accumulate interest as well? Not sure how to properly account for that though. Then again I could be misinterpreting continuous as "consistent," i.e. the money is deposited consistently at the start of each year, not throughout the year.

Comment: The first looks correct to me. In the case where there's no interest, its $dB/dt = 5000$ and in the case where there's no continual deposit but the balance just grows interest, its the second. Note that you are not assuming that $B(0)=5000$, which would indicate all the 5000 deposited initially.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer the 5000 in the first case is continually generating interest. After a small timestep $dt$, $B(dt) \approx 1.07 B(0) + 5000 dt$, so a tiny portion of the 5000 goes into calculating the next timestep $B(2dt) \approx  1.07 B(dt) + 5000 dt$, and so on